# Convert android library project to jar file with resources (libs and build folder)

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I make an android library project. It has some jar files and .so files.

1. I export this project as jar file

   - File->export->jar file->check my project with all folders and files,
   - uncheck AndroidManifest.xml,
   - check Export all output folders for check project
   - check Export java source files and resources
   - -> finish.

But when I add to my another project(libs folder) and add this on javaBuildPath, after run in the log cat show "NoClassDefFound Error (one of the jar file)".
How can I fix this problem?

**Edit:** I'm using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

1- Right Click on Project –> Export —> Java –> JarFile

2-Select only the src checkbox ie the (pacakages) in Top-Left Window. Don’t Select anything in Top-Right Window if some thing is selected remove marks .

3-Select Only Export generates Class Files and Resources

4-In Options Select only Compress the contents of the jar file (it's not important)

To add your External Jar to Your File

1-Right click on project –> Select Properties –> Java Build Path —> libraries –> Add External Jar Files –> Click OK

2-CLEAN your Project

Must clean and build.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work, It doesn't work for me, I have some resource . I think should find another way for do this.